# I opened the review queue today and am suspended from it

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits, review-suspension

I seem to have a 2 day suspension, but I don't have a recollection of failing any audits.

[Here's the example of a "failed" audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5034384), but this seems like a legitimate post, not to mention other people reviewed the same. I've been taking my time and this happened when I opened it about an hour later.

Comment: Why are you approving minor edits to a four year old question that should have been closed?

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong with the edit itself, it seems fine (regardless of the question). I suppose it could be "too minor" but I can see both ways. However, the main thing is that when I reviewed this, it wasn't an audit. (And continued reviewing other things after that review)

Comment: @BilltheLizard: That's quite a harsh ban IMO. Whilst a minor edit, it *does* fix all issues with the spelling and grammar of the post. The suggested edit queue is there to review suggested edits, not review whether a question should be closed or not. Whilst I agree that edits that *smear lipstick on a pig* should be rejected, this isn't that obvious.

Comment: @Matt Only two of those edits are actual corrections. The other two were probably made to get past the 6 character change limit. This is an edit that really didn't need to be made.

Comment: @Mat, I dispute that. "should" adds nothing, the original was correct also. "on" is more wrong than "of". "an SQL" is only more correct than "a SQL" in the same way that "a URL" is more correct than "an URL" - in practice I pronounce both as words rather than spelling them out.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I didn't mean to suggest it was the best edit. I just think there are *far* worse reviewers out there than the people who accepted this edit. Hell, I reckon I'd have accepted it.

Comment: @Bill don't you issue a warning before striking with a manual review ban?

Comment: Also, whilst Rogue's 85% approve rate isn't awful, I'm very glad to see aterai with their 98.5% approve rate will have been given a time out too.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've never issued a manual ban myself. I have heard other mods complain that people weren't paying attention to warnings, so it looks like they've moved directly to short bans. There are a *lot* of people banned from the review queues right now.

Comment: Editing a post makes it active, thus pushing it up on the first page (usually). Since this wasn't a *necessary* edit, it should have been rejected in my opinion. A ban without warning, however? Seems harsh. But drastic situations call for drastic measures. Mods can't know who will and who won't listen to warnings.

Comment: The thing is, a 2 day review ban is harsh in the same way that your employer making you take 2 extra days paid leave is harsh.

Comment: @OGHaza You get *paid* for this? I need to look over my contract...

Comment: @Bill I agree it's too harsh in this specific case, that's one bad review decision but most others I've seen are totally fine.

Comment: @J.Steen haha my point is, they lose nothing but the ability to review, in the same way you'd be losing nothing but the ability to do your work. (whoops, didn't realise my original comment was in reply to you - i'd have realised this didn't need explanation)

Comment: @OGHaza Of course, I totally agree. I was joking. Having a review ban is not a big punishment, it's just a bit harsh without any warning in this case. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I agree. See my answer.

Comment: @Rogue out of curiosity I have reviewed a few of your approved/rejected edits. You are definitely [**NOT** a robo-reviewer](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5034382) so I am also curious to hear an explanation to why you have been suspended from reviewing...

Comment: `However, the main thing is that when I reviewed this, it wasn't an audit.` So you don't care about taking the right action if the post isn't an audit?  You think that users can do the wrong thing as much as they want as long as they don't do the wrong thing on audits?  At the end of the day, it's the audits that don't matter in the least.  it's just a way of determining if you're doing the right thing *when it really matters*.  If you're not doing the right thing when it really matters, you shouldn't be reviewing.

Comment: @Servy at the time it was more about the fact that I didn't understand how a non-audit question got a suspension. I have information that it was a manual ban now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was a manual ban from a moderator, not a ban based on failed audits. Short bans are being handed out in cases of bad reviews because warnings weren't getting people's attention. There are more details in the comments, but the short answer to why this was a bad review is that the edit really didn't need to be made. None of the changes substantially improved the post.

Given that a spot check of your other reviews looks fine, you haven't failed any audits recently, and the ban seems to have served its purpose (it got your attention), I'll lift the ban in this case.

In the future, please (everyone) make sure you're approving only quality edits that add value to a post. If an edit looks like it was "padded" to get past the 6 character diff limit, think twice about whether the changes need to be approved. (I'm sure you can find instances where a 1-to-5 character diff can completely change the meaning of a post, but this isn't one of them.)

Comment: examples of the "bad reviews" that lead to the suspension? (not for me- for others to see what is considered a good/bad review) or was it based on this one example the OP links to? I also see some questionable "too minor" on removing `MVC` from titles etc. Can we start officialy justifying what is a good/bad edit?

Comment: @mehow It looks like it was only based on this one. All three reviewers of this post were banned at the same time. It's up to moderator discretion to ban people when they see bad reviews on suggested edits. I'm really not sure if we're going to be able to draw a clear, straight line between good and bad edits.